# solidity : bytecode optimization : require( condition ) issue

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, solidity, bytecode, remix

I have a solidity code which uses an optimization=200 in remix.
I'm suspicious if optimization is buggy on my code.

when I use for example :

```
mapping(address => uint8)  allowedUsers;

function   doSomething(address wallet) external {
    ...
    require( allowedUsers[wallet]!=1, "User already set" );
    
    allowedUsers[wallet]=1;
    ...
```

if I run it on binance mainnet or under rinkeby, there is no issue.
But sometimes randomly when used on ethereum mainnet I'm getting
revert error "User already set".
What is strange, It occurs on the first function call for a wallet. But not always.
It seems mapping & require have issues together. because it can occur on another require with mapping not just as on this example.

I cannot disable optimization since bytecode is nearly 25400 bytes out of 25476 allowed.

Any idea what's wrong?

I'm using solidity 0.8.15

Comment: Optimization dose not affect the logic, check allowedUsers array and wallet param you are passing.

Comment: What's strange, It works fine under BSC & rinkeby.  allowedUsers is just an example to explain the issue... I already had such problem when I deployed an NFT contract...  now it occurred again on a non-nft contract.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was something completely different, and was happening in the ethereum mempool.

I understand what happened : I've been front-runned by a MEV BOT. It detected  an ETH transaction was sent from my smartcontract, and sent a copy-cat of the transaction earlier than mine.

I've put counter-actions to avoid it. it's okay now.